# Jpa/Hibernate map foreign key without relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, domain-driven-design, many-to-one

In JPA/Hibernate, is it possible to express a foreign key without adding a relationship?

In DDD in aggregate root I would like to have an id of other aggregate root - I don't want to have a reference to this aggregate, only id. Is it possible to enforce foreign key by hibernate? (I use hibernate auto schema generation).

EG

```
@Entity
Person {
    ...        
}
@Entity
Event {
    @Id
    private long eventId;

    @ForeignKey(references Person.id)
    private long personId;

    // I don't want to map it as @ManyToOne Person
}
```

I don't want to use @ManyToOne, because I don't want to store a reference to other aggregate in Event aggregate. It would be DDD antipattern.

Comment: Could you explain why you do not want to use  `@ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `columnDefinition` in `@Column` to add the constraint.

```
@Column(columnDefintion="bigint references Person(id)")
private long personId;
```

Note that you would need to use database specific SQL type and syntax for the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [importing script file](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-script-files).

> 4.1. Importing script files
>
> To customize the schema generation process, the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` configuration property must be used to provide other scripts files that Hibernate can use when the `SessionFactory` is started.
>
> `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="schema-generation.sql" />`
>
> Hibernate is going to execute the script file after the schema is automatically generated.